# Running Django Custom Management Command - Path Issues

Tags: python, django

I don't understand why this doesn't find the command:

```
khandelwal@simba:/opt/code/cdcschool$ python schoolcommand/manage.py createcampaign
Unknown command: 'createcampaign'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

When this works fine:

```
khandelwal@simba:/opt/code/cdcschool$ cd schoolcommand/
khandelwal@simba:/opt/code/cdcschool/schoolcommand$ python manage.py createcampaign
Error: Provide: <type start_date end_date>
```

This is where my command is located:

```
$ ls schoolcommand/management/
commands  __init__.py  __init__.pyc

$ ls schoolcommand/management/commands/
campaignmanager.py   createcampaign.py   __init__.py
campaignmanager.pyc  createcampaign.pyc  __init__.pyc
```

How do I fix it so that I can do:

```
khandelwal@simba:/opt/code/cdcschool$ python schoolcommand/manage.py createcampaign
```

Here are the values of my PYTHONPATH, DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE and the one place my settings.py is located.

```
khandelwal@simba:/opt/code/cdcschool$ ls
Procfile  README  requirements.txt  schoolcommand
khandelwal@simba:/opt/code/cdcschool$ echo $PYTHONPATH

khandelwal@simba:/opt/code/cdcschool$ echo $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

khandelwal@simba:/opt/code/cdcschool$ find . -name settings.py
./schoolcommand/settings.py
khandelwal@simba:/opt/code/cdcschool$
```

Comment: There was a typo in my final question - This has now been fixed.

Comment: You may have too many `settings.py` modules floating around.  Please provide a summary of the directory structure showing all the places you have `settings.py`.  Or.  Your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` has a "relative" path in it.  Include the value of this environment variable.  Or.  Your `PYTHONPATH` has a relative path in it.  Please include the settings of this environment variable, also.

Comment: Added the contents of the environment variables above, and the locations of the settings file.

Comment: and why would you want to run `python PATH\manage.py COMMAND` rather than `python manage.py COMMAND`???

Answer (score 7):

When you use Django, there are two important rules.

First.

You have a `settings.py` file which **must** be used by the web server and **all** the manage.py commands.  All of them.

The default place to look for the `settings.py` file is the current working directory.  You can change this with the `PYTHONPATH` and the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable.

The `manage.py` is created for you in the same directory as the `settings.py`.

You can use `django-admin.py --settings=some.module` if you don't want to use `manage.py`.

Second.

The `manage.py` commands do not have any "path" to them.  They're all just one-word commands, no matter where they happen to live in your application tree.

You **never** do this: `python schoolcommand/manage.py createcampaign` unless (somehow) your `settings.py` is not in the same directory as your `manage.py`.

You **normally** do this:

```
cd /path/to/your/settings
python manage.py createcampaign
```

If your settings is in `code/schoolcommand` that means that your web site and all your commands will operate in that directory.